# What is the use for an alchemist's lab?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, crafting

If the alchemist's lab (500gp) provides +2 circumstance bonus on craft(alchemy) checks, what use is there for it if a [masterwork artisan's tools](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#artisansTools) (55gp) already provides the same bonus on **ANY** craft checks?

> **Artisan’s Tools**
>   These special tools include the items needed to pursue any craft. Without them, you have to use improvised tools (-2 penalty on Craft checks), if you can do the job at all.
>
> **Artisan’s Tools, Masterwork**
>   These tools serve the same purpose as artisan’s tools (above), but masterwork artisan’s tools are the perfect tools for the job, so you get a +2 circumstance bonus on Craft checks made with them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The [alchemist's lab](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#alchemistsLab) specifically overrides the more general [masterwork tool](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#toolMasterwork) and the [masterwork artisan's tools](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#artisansToolsMasterwork)

- Most skills don't need tools. However, a craftsman usually needs different artisan's tools for each Craft skill.
- You can buy a masterwork tool for a skill. The masterwork tool for the skill Craft is masterwork artisan's tools.
- If a *specific* masterwork tool is available for a skill (and you want that circumstance bonus) you *must* buy that instead. The specific masterwork tool for the skill Craft (alchemy) is an alchemist's lab.

Below are relevant passages from the *Player's Handbook*. They don't make a lot of sense when considered individually, which is why I included the above summary.

The *Player's Handbook* on [Favorable and Unfavorable Conditions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/usingSkills.htm#favorableAndUnfavorableConditions) says

> Give the skill user a +2 circumstance bonus to represent conditions that improve performance, such as having **the perfect tool for the job**, getting help from another character (see Combining Skill Attempts, page 65), or possessing unusually accurate information. (64)

Emphasis mine. The *Player's Handbook* later describes the [masterwork tool](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#toolMasterwork) as follows:

> **This well-made item is the perfect tool for the job**. It grants a +2 circumstance bonus on a related skill check (if any). **Some examples** of this sort of item from Table 7–8 **include masterwork artisan’s tools, masterwork thieves’ tools, disguise kit, climber’s kit, healer’s kit, and masterwork musical instrument.** This entry covers just about anything else. **Bonuses provided by multiple masterwork items used toward the same skill check do not stack**, so masterwork pitons and a masterwork climber’s kit do not provide a +4 bonus if used together on a Climb check. (130-1)

Emphasis mine. Note that the list of examples isn't exhaustive and that Craft *is* a skill. The *Player's Handbook* also describes [artisan's tools](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#artisansTools):

> These special tools include the items needed to pursue any craft. Without them, you have to use improvised tools (–2 penalty on Craft checks), if you can do the job at all. (129)

And [masterwork artisan's tools](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#artisansToolsMasterwork):

> These tools serve the same purpose as [artisan’s tools](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#artisansTools)..., but **masterwork artisan’s tools are the perfect tools for the job**, so you get a +2 circumstance bonus on Craft checks made with them. (129-30)

Emphasis mine. Finally, the *Player's Handbook* describes the [alchemist's lab](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#alchemistsLab), in part, as follows:

> This set of equipment includes beakers, bottles, mixing and measuring containers, and a miscellany of chemicals and substances. **An alchemist’s lab always has the perfect tool for making alchemical items**, so it provides a +2 circumstance bonus on Craft (alchemy) checks. (129)

Emphasis mine. When a skill lacks a specific perfect tool, you buy a generic masterwork tool or, for a Craft skill, generic masterwork artisan's tools for that Craft skill. The skill Craft (alchemy) *has* a perfect tool available: the alchemist's lab. This makes *both* a masterwork tool *and* masterwork artisan's tools unavailable for the skill Craft (alchemy) in the same way you can't buy a masterwork tool for the skill Heal instead of a [healer's kit](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#healersKit). To get the +2 circumstance bonus for using the perfect tool on Craft (alchemy) skill checks you use an alchemist's lab.

Comment: Just checking. The way it's presented made me wonder whether you might have copied and pasted the text and forgotten to edit it to show a different source, but it sounds like I was worrying for nothing. Sorry about that.

Comment: I was trying to get all of that across in my answer - but I got lost in my own words.

Comment: @Ruut Victims of our own knowledge, I guess. After having internalized all this for so long, I, too, found this surprisingly difficult to articulate.

Answer (score -1):

This is an easy one!

[Circumstance Bonuses](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#circumstanceModifier) stack; get your alchemy lab (+2) and your masterwork artisan's tools (alchemy) (+2) and enjoy +4 on your checks.

Comment: That isn't necessarily true. They both state 'perfect tool' in their description. A savvy DM could very well say that the circumstance bonus would both come from tools and therefore would be the same source. Down-voted until there is evidence that a Perfect Tool and a Perfect Tool are not the same source.

Comment: @Ruut Non-stacking only applies to the *same* source, not similar sources. These are two different things, ergo they are not the same source.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If 3 mages cast Ray of Enfeeblement onto an orc, the orc would have penalties from all 3 mages?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Perfect Tool would still be the same source mechanically - that is what I am getting at. Using two different Masterwork Books; one written by Elminster and the other written by Khelban Blackstaff; should not and would not give me a +4 to Spellcraft.

Comment: [Bonuses provided by multiple masterwork items used toward the same skill check do not stack.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm#toolMasterwork)